# Is there a way to display time / clock on the Windows 7 logon / login screen?

Tags: windows-7, login, time

Seems like a simple thing to ask, right? Show the system time (date is optional) on the login (logon) screen in Windows 7. Yet Win7 doesn't seem to be able to do that using just the default software tools.

The solutions I've seen so far involve suspicious-looking shareware that are basically screensavers. I don't want that, since a screensaver takes a while to become activated. I want the current system time to be displayed on that screen at all times.

This is needed by users with time restrictions. If the time is not displayed, it's hard for such an user to know when they are allowed to use the system - especially in this day and age when not many people carry a wristwatch.

Comment: Most people do carry cellphones though. :)

Comment: So if Win7 itself can't do that, and you don't trust "suspicious" shareware, what are you expecting to find?

Answer (score 0):

When login screen is on. services are running, but not processes. How do you except microsoft OS developers to know and determine your custom setting ?
For these, there are system administrators who buy custom tools for controlling and monitoring the workers computers.
you can change how to wallpaper looks like and maybe there are shareware application that run as service and then show time on the screen (but i dont know such).